# THREE.JS Creating face with more than 3 vertices

Tags: three.js, face

I have a code:

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry(); 

    camera.position.set(1500, -1300, 1500);

    var vertex = [ 
        new THREE.Vector3(1000, 0, 1000),
        new THREE.Vector3(2000, 0, 1000),
        new THREE.Vector3(2000, 0, 2000)
    ];
    geometry.vertices = vertex;
    var faces = [ new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2) ];
    geometry.faces = faces;

    var Material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 'blue'} );
    var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, Material );
    scene.add(object);
```

And the result is:

[image]

I want to have more vertices in my face. Is it possible?
When I just try:

```
var vertex = [ 
    new THREE.Vector3(1000, 0, 1000),
    new THREE.Vector3(2000, 0, 1000),
    new THREE.Vector3(2000, 0, 2000),
    new THREE.Vector3(2000, 0, 1000)
];
```

... it doesn't work :(

Comment: You can't have a face with more than 3 vertices. Have a look at this [example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=shapes#webgl_geometry_shapes). Use `THREE.Shape()` and `THREE.ShapeGeometry()`/`THREE.ShapeBufferGeometry()`.

Comment: No. As the name `Face3` indicates, it always consists of three vertices.

Comment: Here are two good articles on how OpenGL (and by extension WebGL) work with vertices to draw shapes. ( [1](https://open.gl/drawing), [2](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives) ) I've linked directly to `Trignales` in the second article because that is most relevant to your question--GL draws in triangles, so it's best to think in triangles. Your vertex buffer can have more than three vertices in it, but you must then segment it into individual triangles using indexing.