# How can I create a face from an arbitrarily sized array of vertices?

Tags: three.js

[image]

I have a 3D shape created in UnrealEd 2.0, as shown above. This can be exported into "T3D" format or parsed from the saved map file directly, which looks like the following:

```
Begin PolyList
   Begin Polygon Item=Wall
      Origin   +00212.077362,+00512.000000,-00128.000000
      Normal   +00000.707107,+00000.707107,+00000.000000
      TextureU +00000.707107,-00000.707107,+00000.000000
      TextureV +00000.000000,+00000.000000,-00001.000000
      Vertex   +00212.077362,+00512.000000,-00128.000000
      Vertex   +00212.077362,+00512.000000,+00128.000000
      Vertex   +00512.000000,+00212.077347,+00128.000000
      Vertex   +00512.000000,+00212.077347,-00128.000000
   End Polygon
   Begin Polygon Item=Wall
      Origin   +00512.000000,+00212.077347,-00128.000000
      Normal   +00001.000000,+00000.000000,+00000.000000
      TextureU +00000.000000,-00001.000000,+00000.000000
      TextureV +00000.000000,+00000.000000,-00001.000000
      Vertex   +00512.000000,+00212.077347,-00128.000000
      Vertex   +00512.000000,+00212.077347,+00128.000000
      Vertex   +00512.000000,-00212.077393,+00128.000000
      Vertex   +00512.000000,-00212.077393,-00128.000000
   End Polygon
   Begin Polygon Item=Wall
      Origin   +00512.000000,-00212.077393,-00128.000000
      Normal   +00000.707107,-00000.707107,-00000.000000
      TextureU -00000.707107,-00000.707107,-00000.000000
      TextureV -00000.000000,+00000.000000,-00001.000000
      Vertex   +00512.000000,-00212.077393,-00128.000000
      Vertex   +00512.000000,-00212.077393,+00128.000000
      Vertex   +00212.077255,-00512.000061,+00128.000000
      Vertex   +00212.077255,-00512.000061,-00128.000000
   End Polygon
   Begin Polygon Item=Wall
      Origin   +00212.077255,-00512.000061,-00128.000000
      Normal   -00000.000000,-00001.000000,+00000.000000
      TextureU -00001.000000,+00000.000000,+00000.000000
      TextureV -00000.000000,+00000.000000,-00001.000000
      Vertex   +00212.077255,-00512.000061,-00128.000000
      Vertex   +00212.077255,-00512.000061,+00128.000000
      Vertex   -00212.077347,-00512.000000,+00128.000000
      Vertex   -00212.077347,-00512.000000,-00128.000000
   End Polygon
   Begin Polygon Item=Wall
      Origin   -00212.077347,-00512.000000,-00128.000000
      Normal   -00000.707107,-00000.707107,-00000.000000
      TextureU -00000.707107,+00000.707107,+00000.000000
      TextureV +00000.000000,+00000.000000,-00001.000000
      Vertex   -00212.077347,-00512.000000,-00128.000000
      Vertex   -00212.077347,-00512.000000,+00128.000000
      Vertex   -00512.000061,-00212.077179,+00128.000000
      Vertex   -00512.000061,-00212.077179,-00128.000000
   End Polygon
   Begin Polygon Item=Wall
      Origin   -00512.000061,-00212.077179,-00128.000000
      Normal   -00001.000000,+00000.000000,+00000.000000
      TextureU +00000.000000,+00001.000000,+00000.000000
      TextureV -00000.000000,+00000.000000,-00001.000000
      Vertex   -00512.000061,-00212.077179,-00128.000000
      Vertex   -00512.000061,-00212.077179,+00128.000000
      Vertex   -00511.999969,+00212.077438,+00128.000000
      Vertex   -00511.999969,+00212.077438,-00128.000000
   End Polygon
   Begin Polygon Item=Wall
      Origin   -00511.999969,+00212.077438,-00128.000000
      Normal   -00000.707107,+00000.707107,+00000.000000
      TextureU +00000.707107,+00000.707107,+00000.000000
      TextureV -00000.000000,+00000.000000,-00001.000000
      Vertex   -00511.999969,+00212.077438,-00128.000000
      Vertex   -00511.999969,+00212.077438,+00128.000000
      Vertex   -00212.077347,+00512.000000,+00128.000000
      Vertex   -00212.077347,+00512.000000,-00128.000000
   End Polygon
   Begin Polygon Item=Wall
      Origin   -00212.077347,+00512.000000,-00128.000000
      Normal   +00000.000000,+00001.000000,+00000.000000
      TextureU +00001.000000,-00000.000000,+00000.000000
      TextureV +00000.000000,+00000.000000,-00001.000000
      Vertex   -00212.077347,+00512.000000,-00128.000000
      Vertex   -00212.077347,+00512.000000,+00128.000000
      Vertex   +00212.077362,+00512.000000,+00128.000000
      Vertex   +00212.077362,+00512.000000,-00128.000000
   End Polygon
   Begin Polygon Item=Cap
      Origin   -00212.077347,+00512.000000,+00128.000000
      Normal   +00000.000000,+00000.000000,+00001.000000
      TextureU +00000.707107,-00000.707107,+00000.000000
      TextureV +00000.707107,+00000.707107,-00000.000000
      Vertex   -00212.077347,+00512.000000,+00128.000000
      Vertex   -00511.999969,+00212.077438,+00128.000000
      Vertex   -00512.000061,-00212.077179,+00128.000000
      Vertex   -00212.077347,-00512.000000,+00128.000000
      Vertex   +00212.077255,-00512.000061,+00128.000000
      Vertex   +00512.000000,-00212.077393,+00128.000000
      Vertex   +00512.000000,+00212.077347,+00128.000000
      Vertex   +00212.077362,+00512.000000,+00128.000000
   End Polygon
   Begin Polygon Item=Cap
      Origin   +00212.077362,+00512.000000,-00128.000000
      Normal   +00000.000000,+00000.000000,-00001.000000
      TextureU -00000.707107,-00000.707107,-00000.000000
      TextureV -00000.707107,+00000.707107,+00000.000000
      Vertex   +00212.077362,+00512.000000,-00128.000000
      Vertex   +00512.000000,+00212.077347,-00128.000000
      Vertex   +00512.000000,-00212.077393,-00128.000000
      Vertex   +00212.077255,-00512.000061,-00128.000000
      Vertex   -00212.077347,-00512.000000,-00128.000000
      Vertex   -00512.000061,-00212.077179,-00128.000000
      Vertex   -00511.999969,+00212.077438,-00128.000000
      Vertex   -00212.077347,+00512.000000,-00128.000000
   End Polygon
End PolyList
```

Adding the vertices to a `Geometry` is no problem as I can use `new THREE.Vector3(X, Y, Z)` for each of the vertices for each polygon, but the problem arises when it comes to adding the faces. All the guides I've come across say to use `Face3`, but this obviously isn't suitable as the faces in this shape mostly consist of *four* points, and eight for the top/bottom.

One of the comments on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49691431/three-js-creating-face-with-more-than-3-vertices) suggests using `ShapeGeometry` but again this isn't suitable as only takes X/Y coordinates.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here - ideally I would like to do something like:

```js
new THREE.Face(0, 1, 2, 3) // side face 1
new THREE.Face(4, 5, 6, 7) // side face 2
// etc.
new THREE.Face(20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27) // top face
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to use more than 3 vertices for a `Face3`. WebGL only renders triangles, and what you're trying to do is known as an "n-gon", which is not possible. You could, however, use your existing vertices to make the triangles to create the cap.

Here are two approaches. In the second one, you could create a center vertex by averaging the position of all radial vertices, and then connect them in a fan pattern:

[image]

Caveat: manually building each vertex like this will look fine with wireframes, but you might need to calculate `normals` if you want to use lights and `uvs` if you want to apply textures.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer; disappointed to hear it's not as easy as I was hoping. Regarding your suggestion to split the surfaces into triangles, do you know if Three.js offers a way of doing this automatically or is this something I'll have to implement myself?

Comment: The easiest thing to do is to just export your T3D file to already have the caps included, so you don't have to do it manually. Alternatively, you could just use [`THREE.CylinderBufferGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/CylinderBufferGeometry), which does all the work for you.

Comment: Maybe it's not very clear from my first screenshot but the caps are actually included already, they're just not split into triangles as UnrealEd doesn't seem to limit the amount of vertices per face. The `CylinderBufferGeometry` (or any other primitive) would be ideal if I was working with simple shapes, but ideally I'd like to be able to render any arbitrary shape. Thanks again - appreciate your input.